# Reference Request: $H^1(\mathfrak g, V)=0$ for semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak g$-module $V$

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-algebras, homology-cohomology

I read the following theorem in the [lecture note](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.745/Notes/Lecture_23_Notes.pdf) of Victor Kac. Let $\mathfrak g$ be a finite-dimensional semisimple Lie algebra over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.

> Theorem(Vanishing Theorem) If $V$ is a finite-dimensional $\mathfrak
>  g$-module, then $H^1(\mathfrak g, V)=0$

I would like to request a reference for this theorem. In particular, I seek an introductory textbook which covers this theorem.

Comment: This is [Whitehead's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead%27s_lemma_(Lie_algebra)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different reference is:

Hilton Stammbach "A course in Homological Algebra", Chap VII, Proposition 5.6 and 6.1.

Moreover, I have to mention that all the Chapter VII is an introduction to cohomology of Lie Algebras and that section 5 and 6 analyze the special case of semisimple Lie algebras.

Answer (score 3):

This theorem appears as Exercise $7.8.4$ in Weibel's An Introduction to Homological Algebra in the chapter on Lie algebra homology and cohomology. It is written as follows

> If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over a field of characteristic $0$, show that $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple iff $H^1(\mathfrak{g}, M) = 0$ for all finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{g}$-modules $M$.

So it doesn't explicitly cover the theorem as you request, but the chapter does provides enough information for the reader to construct the proof themselves, otherwise it wouldn't appear as an exercise!

Answer (score 2):

This is theorem 3.3 from A. L. Onischik and E. B. Vinberg's *Lie Groups and Lie Algebras III*:

**Theorem:** The following properties of a finite-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ are equivalent:

1. $\mathfrak g$ is semisimple;
2. $H^1(\mathfrak g,V)=\{0\}$ for any finite-dimensional $\mathfrak g$-module $V$;
3. any finite-dimensional linear representation of $\mathfrak g$ is completely reducible.